# How do I read the value of a continuous index from spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a problem with Spark Scala get the first value from series key,I create a new RDD like this:

```
[(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(a,4),(b,1),(b,2),(a,3),(a,4),(a,5),(b,8),(b,9)]
```

I want to fetch the result like this:

```
[(a,1),(b,1),(a,3),(b,8)]
```

How can I do this with scala from RDD

Comment: Spark does not maintain the order of your collection, so it's something you can't do with your existing data structure. You need to introduce a key that would be used to sort the data and use a windowing function: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: @lee didnt quite get what you are trying to do ? can you explain what series you are trying to fetch?

Comment: @SumeetSharma I think he wants to keep only the first cuple of each group of consecutive cuples with the same key, but RDD doesn't keep the order so the groups will vary from the initial sequence

Comment: Can you share what you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, in order to be able to use the order of the elements in an RDD, you'd have to somehow represent this order in the data itself. For that purpose exactly, `zipWithIndex` was created - the index is added to the data; Then, with some manipulation (`join` on an RDD with modified indices) we can get what you need:

```
// add index to RDD:
val withIndex = rdd.zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)

// create another RDD with indices increased by one, to later join each element with the previous one
val previous = withIndex.map { case (index, v) => (index + 1, v) }

// join RDDs, filter out those where previous "key" is identical
val result = withIndex.leftOuterJoin(previous).collect {
  case (i, (left, None)) => (i, left) // keep first element in RDD
  case (i, (left, Some((key, _)))) if left._1 != key => (i, left) // keep only elements where the previous key is different
}.sortByKey().values // if you want to preserve the original order...

result.collect().foreach(println)
// (a,1)
// (b,1)
// (a,3)
// (b,8)
```

Comment: Thanks for Tzach Zohar. This is the right answer whick I need. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help; The best way to indicate a helpful answer is to _accept_ it (via the green V mark next to it) or upvote it ;)